# MacOS - Backing up iBooks highlights and notes when switching to new laptop

Tags: macos

I have been using iBooks for reading epub books/files in my work laptop. I'll be switching to a different Mac laptop sometime soon.

I can copy/backup the epub files. But, for backing up the highlights and notes, what are the folders/files I need to copy (backup from old laptop and restore in new laptop).

**UPDATE:** I cannot use iCloud since it is blocked by my company. Also, I prefer not to use Time machine as I don't need a full backup (and there might be limitations on using it in a work laptop as well).

I have heard that highlights are in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iBooksX/Data/Documents/AEAnnotation`. Is it the only location?

1. What are the folders I need to copy and restore to get my highlights and notes back in the new laptop.
2. If the epub files are in a different location in new laptop, would this work? (i.e., I hope the highlights aren't coupled to a machine or the epub files location on the disk).

P.S: I won't be having access to both laptops at the same time. I'll have to hand over the old one in order to get the new one.

Comment: Do you not have Time Machine to migrate from, or at least iCloud, which should sync things like bookmarks/annotations?

Comment: @Tetsujin I cannot use iCloud as it is blocked by my company (yes, this is a company laptop that I use for work). Not willing to use time machine as I don't have a need for a full-blown backup solution.

Comment: You should add details such as this to your question, to save people offering consumer fixes.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wasn't aware iCloud provided this.

Comment: It does - but I wouldn't ever recommend using a private Apple ID on a work computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

Luckily I was able to get hold of both the old and new laptop. I can confirm that copying the contents from `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iBooksX/` was enough to get back the highlights and notes.